# FFMPEG or ImageMagick for image conversion and resizing (speed/memory usage)?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, imagemagick

I stumbled over a situation where I cannot use PHP to convert/resize PNG images to JPG images due to memory limits.

However, there is FFMPEG on the server that I can use from PHP with `shell_exec()`.

So now FFMPEG is used to resize and convert PNG images:

```
ffmpeg -i ".$image_png." -vf scale=1200:-1 ".$image_jpg)
```

However, I wonder how much memory FFMPEG uses for the conversion?

And if it would be better to use ImageMagick instead (regarding speed and memory usage)?

Further research revealed:

> FFMpeg is using the [libswscale](https://ffmpeg.org/libswscale.html) library to resize the input

Answer (score 3):

On linux you can use `time` to measure memory use.

You need to run it as `/usr/bin/time` to make sure you get the `time` program and not the `time` command that's built into the shell. Use `-f` to set what statistics to print --- I usually use `%M` for peak memory use and `%e` for elapsed time.

On this Ubuntu 21.10 desktop I see:

```
$ vipsheader wtc.png
wtc.png: 9372x9372 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, pngload
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e \
    ffmpeg -i wtc.png -vf scale=1200:-1 x.jpg
... snip
572880:3.00
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e \
    magick convert wtc.png -resize 1200x1200 x.jpg
1203976:2.59
$ VIPS_CONCURRENCY=1 /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e \
    vipsthumbnail wtc.png --size 1200x1200 -o x.jpg
66992:2.51
```

So on this largeish PNG image, ffmpeg is 600MB and 3s of runtime, imagemagick is 1.2GB and 2.6s, and libvips is 70MB and 2.5s.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I wonder how much memory FFMPEG uses for the conversion?

Add `-benchmark` and then check the log for line containing `maxrss=` for mem usage.

Comment: Could you clarify *where* to add `-benchmark` to *what* please? And also give some indication of which logs you mean and where they might be found? Thank you.

Comment: It would be added to the ffmpeg command in your post. The log is what ffmpeg prints on stderr during execution.